# split string by character and add to different columns in DataGridView in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, winforms, datagridview

I have this code :

```
string strdata = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);
char[] splitchar = new Char[] { '\x00' };
string[] assetdata = strdata.Split(splitchar, strdata.Length);
```

Buffer is a text data which goes as one row and consists of 4 types of variables. You can see example of Encoded in Unicode buffer following this link : 
http://pastebin.com/ScdGX8it
So there are 4 types of data here which needs to be filled into DataGridView rows separated by 4 columns , so it can me sorted and manipulated after. Assetdata is array with this data separated by each value as a single element , but i need to group them - that is the main problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how you want the data organized then grouped?  You say you want 4 columns of data, but your data dump shows more values than that in each section.

Comment: Actually it is 4 types of data separated by this \x00 character. , so now it looks like a1-b1-c1-d1-a2-b2-c2-d2 and etc where "-" is "\x00" character , and a b c d are types of data , and numbers represent just difference in it. And i want it to be grouped in DataGridView , in columns a b c d with data1 data2 data3 data4 inserted by rows accordingly. Hope that explains what i want. http://grab.by/oL4C - here you can see screenshot , in listbox you see rows with data separated. Now the 4-th type is selected. So i want that to insert to the DataGridView on the top accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way without LINQ, that uses a datatable as the datasource for the datagridview.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("T1");
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("A"), new DataColumn("B"), new DataColumn("C"), new DataColumn("D")});
        for (int i = 0; i < assetdata.Length; i += 4)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[]{assetdata[i],assetdata[i+1],assetdata[i+2],assetdata[i+3]});
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

This way you can modify the datatable and update the datagridview, which will probably give you more options since this fits in more with how the datagridviewwas was designed.

Comment: damn ! this works perfectly ! Thanks so much , i was not thinking about creating data table... Though you need to add -4 at assetdata.Length , or it will give index out of range error.
One more thing - if i have columns already created , how can i force Datasource to use those columns for insertion ? Because it adds new columns now , even if i use the same name.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is your friend. Go through the tutorials on grouping. It should be pretty easy, since you already have a string[]. Once you're done with your query, call the ToIEnumerable() extension  method to bind to a DataGridView.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Thing is that for now even c# is not my friend , as i am learning it for 2 months only... I am trying to avoid use of LINQ because i want to learn how it works as it is...

Comment: LINQ is an integral part of C#/.NET - using it will allow to learn about different pieces of the frameworks, such as: generics, lambda methods, anonymous types, collections/interfaces. If you wanted to do this without LINQ, you could manually create the strongly typed classes, and perform the grouping logic yourself, putting all items in a List<T> when you are done, to bind to a DataGridView.